# how to calculate time interval and divide it by integer in r?

Tags: r, time

i have time string as "08:00","06:00"
and i wanna calculate difference between them
and divide it by 15 mins.

then results should be 8 in integer 
i don't how to code in R

anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this using `difftime`?

```
difftime(
    as.POSIXct("08:00", format = "%H:%M"), 
    as.POSIXct("06:00", format = "%H:%M"), 
    units = "mins") / 15
#Time difference of 8 mins
```

Or to convert to `numeric`

```
as.numeric(
    difftime(as.POSIXct("08:00", format = "%H:%M"), 
    as.POSIXct("06:00", format = "%H:%M"), 
    units = "mins") / 15)
#[1] 8
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy with `lubridate`, where we convert the strings in `hm` format and divide by 15 minutes.

```
library(lubridate)
(hm(a) - hm(b))/minutes(15)
#[1] 8
```

**data**

```
a <- "08:00"
b <- "06:00"
```